# Common noun and article, determiners

Tags: nouns, articles, proper-nouns, determiners, countable-nouns

Should we use articles and determiners before a singular-count common noun all the time? Are there exceptions?

For example:

> A teacher plays an important role.
> but why fish lives in water?

Comment: _Why does **a fish** (singular) live in water?_ or _Why do fish (plural) live in water?_

Comment: "Fish lives in water" is the sentence wrong? i mean live+s

Comment: Yes, it's wrong (unless you have a pet goldfish called Fish!).